# How do I run two copies of firefox?

Tags: firefox

[image]

Modify firefox shortcut did not help

```
-p -no-remote
```

Comment: You need to use `-p profile` and give it a different profile to the instance already running. See [Opening a new instance of your Mozilla application with another profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile)

Answer (score 4):

The PortableApps wrapper around Firefox limits the amount of `firefox.exe` processes. However, if you have Firefox running and attempt to run Firefox Portable alongside it, it will detect this and refuse to open.

To resolve this, you need to write a PortableApps Firefox config file. You can find an example config file in `Other/Source/` called `FireFoxPortable.ini`).

```
[FirefoxPortable]
FirefoxDirectory=App\firefox
ProfileDirectory=Data\profile
SettingsDirectory=Data\settings
PluginsDirectory=Data\plugins
FirefoxExecutable=firefox.exe
AdditionalParameters=
LocalHomepage=
DisableSplashScreen=false
AllowMultipleInstances=false
DisableIntelligentStart=false
SkipCompregFix=false
RunLocally=false
```

The value you need to adjust is `AllowMultipleInstances`, which is by default set to `false`. Set it to `true`, and save the file as `FirefoxPortable.ini` alongside `FirefoxPortable.exe`.